# Wagtail adding new pages

Tags: python, django, workflow, wagtail

My current way of adding new pages to my wagtail site is the following:

1. Edit the installed apps to include my new page

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
     'home',
     'anotherpage',
     'newpage', # this is new

     'wagtail.wagtailforms',
     ...
   ]
   ```
2. Copy the format of `anotherpage` to be my `newpage`

   ```
   cp -rf  anotherpage newpage
   ```
3. Edit my `newpage/models.py` references to `anotherpage` to be `newpage`.
   E.g.

   ```
   class Anotherpage(Page):
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   class Newpage(Page):
   ```

And the `newpage/migrations/0001_initial.py` references

Rename: `mv feedback/templates/info feedback/templates/feedback`

and `mv feedback/templates/feedback/info_page.html feedback/templates/feedback/feedback_page.html`

etc

Then run `python manage.py makemigrations`

Then `python manage.py migrate`

---

**Question**

This workflow feels quite inefficient, is there a better way to be doing any of the above?

I'm new to python and wagtail. Any insight on what I could be doing better would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to create a new `INSTALLED_APPS` entry and app folder for every new page model you create - a single `models.py` file can contain as many page models as you like. Generally I'd recommend one app for each major area of your site - for example, you could have a `blog` app containing `BlogPage`, `BlogIndex` and `BlogArchive` page types. You can even define the page models for your entire site in a single app if you want - although that can get hard to maintain when the file grows very large.

This way, creating a new page model just involves adding the `class Newpage(Page):` definition to the existing `models.py`, running `./manage.py makemigrations`, and adding a new template into the existing template directory.

Additionally, when you do decide to create a new app, you can make use of the `./manage.py startapp some_app_name` command to save having to create files and folders manually.